# Replacing libdb file to upgrade Berkeley DB?

Tags: visual-studio, berkeley-db

I am upgrading the BDB in a project from v4.3 to 6.1. This is how I manage to approach the situation.

I got the impression that **libdb61.lib** contain all that is BDB from [BDB Installation & Build Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_04/html/installation/BDB_Installation.pdf), so I downloaded the latest BDB, built it in BDB's VS project, placed **libdb61.lib** at where **libdb43.lib** is in my VS project, and changed Project_1's 
"Properties > Config Prop > Librarian > Additional Dependencies" to lead to **libdb61.lib**.

I succeeded at building Project_1; however, I got multiple "error LNK2001" when I built Project_2, which depends on Project_1.

Here is one of the Error message:

```
1>Project_1.lib(IndexTable.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl Db::set_bt_compare(int (__cdecl*)(class Db *,
```

I figured my project does not have a file which contains functions like "set_bt_compare()", which is contained in the BDB's "DB" project.

Am I doing it the wrong way? (I am not sure if I can upgrade by simply adding files and changing project properties. In addition, I did not add files like **libdb61.dll, libdb61.exp, libdb61.pdb, etc.**)

Answer (score 0):

Read through all of the "Upgrading Applications to Berkeley DB.X.Y.Z" chapters. You can't just substitute db-6.x into db-4.x (although the API is mostly the same, there are changes).